# Can't remove gridlines when plotting with geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

The standard means of removing gridlines seem futile when plotting with `geom_sf`.

For instance, if we plot a simple `ggplot` object, this works to remove the grid

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(disp, hp)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

returns

[image: scatterplot no grid]

but the same code fails to remove the grid when you plot using `geom_sf`

```
"shape/nc.shp" %>% 
  system.file(
    package = "sf"
  ) %>% 
  st_read(
    quiet = TRUE
    ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This issue was raised on the [`ggplot2` github site](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2071). You can remove the gridlines by either of:

1. Setting the colour of the gridlines to be transparent with `theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"))`
2. Adding `coord_sf(datum = NA)` *after* calling `geom_sf`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to remove the gridlines is to change the scale using `scale_x_continuous`:

```
library(ggplot2)
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

crs_robinson = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m no_defs"

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = world, color="grey70", fill="grey70")  +
  theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_line(colour = "grey70", size=2),
        axis.text.x= element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  labs(title = str_c("Map of without gridlines") ,
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-180, 180)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-89.999, 89.999)) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m no_defs", expand = TRUE)no_defs", expand = TRUE)
```

PS: Note that that for `x scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-90, 90))` gives an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = data, colour = NA)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).